# Second handle in plotyy failing to run through for loop

Tags: matlab

My code is intended to generate a series of plots (of different colors) depending on the value of *percentsolar* (hence the 'for' loop running from 1 to the length of percentsolar). The first series of plots (arrays stored in *percentimprovement1*) should be plotted on the 1st y-axis and the second series of plots (arrays stored in *sizup21*) should be plotted on the 2nd y-axis.  Unfortunately, the second "series" of plots shows up as only a single line even though the arrays inside *sizeup21* are different (i.e. they should not show up as the same line).

Below is my code:

```
dashes = {':', '-'};
colors = {'b', 'r', 'm', 'c', 'k', 'w', 'g', 'y'};
for e=1:length(percentsolar)
    [ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(randomentries, percentimprovement1(:,e), randomentries, sizeup21(:,e));
    set(h1,'LineStyle',dashes{1});
    set(h1,'color', colors{e});
    set(ax(1),'YLim',[0 100]);
    set(ax(1),'YTick',0:20:100);
    set(h2,'LineStyle', dashes{2});
    set(h2,'color',colors{e});
    set(ax(2),'YLim',[0 max(max(sizeup21))])
    set(ax(2),'YTick',0:1:max(max(sizeup21)))
    hold on;
end
```

Comment: make a minimal code that works please, we don't have `percentsolar,randomentries, percentimprovement1,sizeup21...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with `plotyy` and hold. `plotyy` creates two plot handles. Hold on works not as intended.

Workaround:

```
%add first tow data sets:
[axis, l, r] = plotyy(...)
hold(axis(1),'on')
hold(axis(2),'on')
%add another data set, left axis
plot(axis(1), x, y)
%add another data set, right axis
plot(axis(2), x, y)
```

Comment: Yes, there are 2 axes with `plotyy`, so hold needs the explicit syntax.  Good catch.

Comment: Great catch, indeed! Thanks.